# Android listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created an android application. In that application when I click the listview item it should display in the another listview in the same layout.

Is this possible in android?

Answer (score 2):

Well, quick snippet:

```
public Activity1 extends Activity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        // stuffs here
        ....

        // ListView event
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("SelectedString", listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }
}


public Activity2 extends Activity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        // stuffs here
        ....

        String valueFromActivity1 = getIntent().getString("SelectedString");

        // ok now, u've got value from Activity1, do whatever w/ it

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you have to make intent and pass the variables of the current selected item of the listview to that intent and display the dynamic listview for that Item